# Failed for building the Angular app for production build (ng build --prod)

Tags: angular

I am using the 3rd party module called angular-star-rating in my app, and it is built and running perfectly fine when I run my app with "ng serve". But when I am trying to build my app with the AOT enabled (ng build --prod) for deploying to the real server, then it will fail to build it.

Here is the error message I got during the build:

"ERROR in Unexpected value 'StarRatingModule in C:/MyApp/angular/node_modules/angular-star-rating/dist/index.d.ts' imported by the module 'SharedModule in C:/MyApp/angular/src/app/modules/shared.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation."

Btw, I am running Angular version 8.3.25 and the angular-star-rating nodule version I am using is 3.0.8.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Angular Star Rating is a Angular 10+ component, so I think that's the reason - you should not use it with Ng8, assuming you have two different angular versions loaded by webpack

Comment: That is not true. You can use Angular 8 with Angular Star Rating with version 3.0.X. In fact, as I mentioned in my post that I was running perfectly fine when using "ng serve" Angular CLI command. Everything works perfectly fine, but it failed to compile when I am trying to build the app with AOT flag turned on.

Comment: I think you should try to update to v5.1.0, as it's the closest version for you, see https://github.com/BioPhoton/angular-star-rating/commit/eb4bb2b13ce8c68e872daa9b266b21dffe769b2b

Comment: And the difference you see might be cause by "aot": true in your angular.json for prod build (for older Ng versions it was off for nonProd builds)